# Problema con Nav-Tabs

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

**Problema con `Nav-Tabs`**

Buenas, tengo un problema con el `nav-tabs` de `bootstrap`, la cuestión es que seguí los ejemplos que están en la misma pagina para la creación de los `nav-tabs` y no se que problema puedo tener, como mira en `tab "profile"` muestra ese formulario, aquí por ejemplo tengo el formulario de perfil y su correspondiente `nav-tab` que muestra ese formulario.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta este punto todo parece estar correcto, pero el problema surge a continuación, cuando al momento de dar click en el `tab` de "notificaciones" aparece lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se me aparece el titulo que coloco para el otro `nav` que es "notificaciones" , no tengo idea que sucede, seguí los pasos y aun no puedo solucionar.

**Mi código `HTML`**

```
       <div class="col-xl-8 col-md-6">
           <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">
              <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link active" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" id="messages-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#messages" role="tab" aria-controls="messages" aria-selected="false">Notificaciones</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

**Código `HTML` Para llamar al `Nav` Perfil**

```
<div class="tab-content py-4">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="profile">
                <h4 class="m-y-2">Perfil de Usuario</h4>
                  <div class="tab-pane" id="">
```

**Código `HTML` para llamar al `nav` Notificaciones**

```
            <div class="tab-content py-4">
                        <div class="tab-pane active" id="messages">
                            <h4 class="m-y-2">Notificaciones</h4>
                              <div class="tab-pane" id="">
```

Comment: A riesgo de recalcar algo que parece evidente en tu código: ¿Los elementos `.tab-pane` los tienes en contenedores `.tab-content` distintos, o usas el mismo elemento `.tab-content` para poder los dos elementos `.tab-pane`?

Comment: Por favor revisa [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) para que podamos ayudarte de mejor manera.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo creo que tu problema es que tienes varios tab-pane active, solo deberia haber uno y los demas solo tab-pane, por otro lado  no noto que estes cerrando donde debe ser los `<div>` a menos que solo sea por el recorte.

Adicional podrias revisar que estes cargando los js de boostrap y claro jquery que es requerido para funcionar correctamente.